# How should I use lists in terraform 0.12 so changing the order of the list doesnt destroy items?

Tags: terraform

I have a list I want to loop over to create resources:

```
variable "mylist" {
  description     = "my list"
  default         = ["a","b","c"]
}

resource "aws_instance" "sdfsdfd" {
  count     = length(var.mylist)
  tags = element(var.bommie_computer_name, count.index)
```

How can I have terraform not destory resources if the order of the array changes? I want to be able to change `["a","b","c"]` to `["c","b","a"]` and have terraform not destroy and recreate anything. Do I have to use for_each to get this behavior?

Comment: Yes you have to use `for_each` so that Terraform will index based on content instead of position of the element in the list.

Comment: that sounds like the answer then. i have another question about this inside of modules but ill open another post

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for_each` instead of `count` whenever possible so if you change the list, it won't try to recreate resources.

```
variable "mylist" {
  description     = "my list"
  default         = ["a","b","c"]
}

resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  for_each = toset(var.mylist)

  # ...
}
```

Comment: @ SomeGuyOnAComputer , at least as per the current documentation, there is no `set `function in terraform , the correct function as of now is [toset](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/v1.1.x/functions/toset)

Comment: I changed it to `toset()` which is new. Good catch.